# Highlighting in Preview not visible in other software

Tags: pdf, preview, formatting

#### Is there a way to make highlighting done in [Preview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(Mac_OS)) visible in other software?

In particular interested in whether it can be seen in [Adobe Reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Acrobat).

Really would like to avoid installing Adobe as it requires frequent updates and seems like a resource hog.

I think this is essentially the reverse of this question: [Different ways of displaying documents between Adobe Reader and Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163220/different-ways-of-displaying-documents-between-adobe-reader-and-preview)

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why you have problem seeing in other apps highlighting (and other annotations) made in Preview, but just in case: after you've made all your annotations including highlights, press Cmd + S or File -> Save in Preview app. All your additions shall now be visible in any other apps.